# sigmav2 - nodes have same position. How to solve?

Tags: sigma.js

We have a sigma instance that is based on lat/long coordinates.
Nodes might have the same position.

How can we solve this with relative ease?

One way we thought was to group all the nodes with the same coordinates into a single node and maybe add an onclick listener that expands it with forceatlas2.

Would that be possible? How about the performance with 1000 nodes and 2k edges?

Thx

Comment: it's not clear in your question, which layout you will use ? Is it static (x & y are lat/long) or are you using an algo (fa2) ?
If you are using FA2, your nodes will not be at the same position even if they have the same lt/lng

Answer (score 0):

About performances, there is really no problem with your volumetry.

About your issue with the same coordinates, in your case, I will :

- create one node in the graph per geo-coordinates
- store an array of items in nodes
- put the size of the array as the node size
- do something on the node's label (concat names ?)
- optional : add a popin on node hover with a custom html render that display your list of items

Comment: BTW, you can check https://codesandbox.io/s/sigma-with-leaflet-lepn9 to see how to display a graph on top of leaflet